# jQuery AwesomeCloud tag links

Tags: jquery, canvas, click

I am using the jquery plugin AwesomeCloud to generate some nice looking tag clouds.

https://github.com/indyarmy/jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin

So we have a tagcloud full of words, based on movie genre's.

Here is the demo page: http://indyarmy.com/awesomeCloud/

I want to make the word's clickable, to go to a search page, that will search for movies that have that genre in them.

The canvas is generated dynamically, but I am using php to generate html like this.

```
<span id="genre" data-weight="3">Action</span>
```

As soon as the awesomecloud plugin script runs, it converts all those spans to display:none, and generates the canvas.

Since what I am clicking upon is a dynamically generated canvas, I am not able so far, to generate a click event, and therefore get the current word value.

Any suggestions or tips?

Thank you kindly for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this fork: https://github.com/fguimara/jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin

They've added that functionality.

You have to change something like this:

```
<span data-weight="18">Google</span>
```

for this:

```
<span data-weight="18"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible (I've been researching the same problem): https://github.com/indyarmy/jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin/issues/5